# Download dataframe as csv from Flask

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask

I am trying to download the dataframe as csv using button click but unable to figure it out how - Please help me as I am new to flask

here is the code -

**df** is the pandas dataframe that i want to download as csv

Flask code

```
@app.route('/submit',methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    
    ** So here is some code for manipulation ** 
    

    df = calc.get_data(prdrop,fr_value,sumprfit,fitids)

    

    return render_template('plot.html',url=plot_url)
```

Plot.html - it gives some graph and a button to download the datasheet as csv

```
<body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{url}}" alt="Chart" height="auto" width="80%">
      <form action="/download" method="POST">
        <input type="Submit" value="Download excel" >
      </form>
</body>
```

Now I understand that I need a new url route to get that df into that and then allow user to download it, could you please help me out regarding how will I access the dataframe in new url and allow user to download it as csv

Answer (score 2):

Flask:

html:
`<a href="{{url_for('get_csv', filename= 'some_csv')}}" id="download" class="btn btn-outline-info">Download</a>`

```
@app.route('/submit',methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    
    ** So here is some code for manipulation ** 
    

    df = calc.get_data(prdrop,fr_value,sumprfit,fitids)
    session["some_csv"] = df.to_csv(index=False)
    
    return render_template('plot.html',url=plot_url)
    
    
@app.route("/get_csv/<filename>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_csv(filename):

    df = session["some_csv"]
    try:
        return send_file(df,
                         mimetype='"text/csv"',
                         as_attachment=True,
                         attachment_filename=filename
                         )

    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
```

Comment: df = calc.get_data(prdrop,fr_value,sumprfit,fitids) won't work in different function because paramters to this function call are not passed

Comment: apologies, I forgot. Take a look now

Comment: how do I edit my html file with "filename" parameter

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\okalange\\PycharmProjects\\Flow_Flask\\flaskr\\Flow,Pressure,"Pressure 1/2"" Fitting"\r\n0.0,0.0,0.0\r\n1.0,1.0,1.0282671378872694\r\n2.0,2.0,2.1130685515490777\r\n3.0,3.0,3.2544042409854246\r\n4.0,4.0,4.45227420619631\r\n5.0,5.0,5.706678447181735\r\n'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217566/discussion-between-omi-and-marphlap).

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument it is not able to download it as csv

Answer (score 2):

You could use sessions. For example:

#### Python file

First part:

```py
import io
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, send_file
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)

# Set the secret key to some random bytes and keep it secret.
# A secret key is needed in order to use sessions.
app.secret_key = b"_j'yXdW7.63}}b7"
```

Submit function:

```py
@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def submit():    
    # Example dataframe 
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data={
            "city": ["Seville", "London", "Berlin"],
            "country": ["Spain", "United Kingdom", "Germany"]
        }
    )
    
    # Store the CSV data as a string in the session
    session["df"] = df.to_csv(index=False, header=True, sep=";")

    return render_template("plot.html")
```

Download function:

```py
@app.route("/download", methods=["POST"])
def download():
    # Get the CSV data as a string from the session
    csv = session["df"] if "df" in session else ""
    
    # Create a string buffer
    buf_str = io.StringIO(csv)

    # Create a bytes buffer from the string buffer
    buf_byt = io.BytesIO(buf_str.read().encode("utf-8"))
    
    # Return the CSV data as an attachment
    return send_file(buf_byt,
                     mimetype="text/csv",
                     as_attachment=True,
                     attachment_filename="data.csv")
```

Last part:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

#### HTML file (*templates/plot.html*)

```
<body>
    <form action="/download" method="POST">
        <input type="Submit" value="Download CSV" >
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to access a already created dataframe in submit() function to a different function like download_csv(), that is the entire problem

Comment: Okay, I understand. I have edited my answer, using now sessions like the answer from the other user. Maybe is it more useful now?

Comment: I got csv in browser as : Flow;Pressure;"Pressure 1/2"" Fitting" 0.0;0.0;0.0 1.0;2.0;2.028267137887269 2.0;4.0;4.113068551549078 3.0;6.0;6.254404240985425 4.0;8.0;8.45227420619631 5.0;10.0;10.706678447181735
How do I download it as attachment?

Comment: I have edited again my response, I think that now it's working as you want. My solution is very similar to the one by the other user.